# Unit Testing Reactive Extensions with a method using Wait

Tags: unit-testing, c#-4.0, system.reactive

I am trying to unit test a method that uses the Wait() method on an IObservable however my test never completes - the Wait never finishes. My test contains the following:

```
var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
var input1 = scheduler.CreateColdObservable<List<string>>(
   new Recorded<Notification<List<string>>>(100, Notification.CreateOnNext(new List<string> { "John", "Harry" })),
   new Recorded<Notification<List<string>>>(200, Notification.CreateOnCompleted<List<string>>())
          );
```

I am using Moq to setup the response on my method by returning input1. For example

```
myObj.Setup(f => f.GetStrings()).Returns(input1);
```

It doesn't actually matter about the details of myObj. I start the scheduler and call my method which contains a Wait(e.g somewhere in my method I call

```
var results = myObj.GetStrings().Wait();
```

But this never returns. I suspect I am using the scheduler wrong but I am not sure.

Regards
Alan

Answer (score 11):

#### Summary

The problem is that you are creating a cold observable and advancing the scheduler *before* you have subscribed to it.

#### Detail

If you call the blocking `Wait()` operation on a single threaded test, you are dead in the water at that point. This is because the `TestScheduler`'s internal clock only advances when you call `Start()` or one of the `AdvanceXXX()` methods and, since you have a cold observable, the event times you specify are relative the point of subscription. There are also some nuances to calling `Start()` which I will explain below.

So, as `Wait` will block, you might try to call it on another thread, but it's still tricky. Consider the following code, which is similar to yours:

```
void Main()
{
    var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
    var source = scheduler.CreateColdObservable(
        new Recorded<Notification<int>>(100, Notification.CreateOnNext(1)),
        new Recorded<Notification<int>>(200, Notification.CreateOnCompleted<int>()));

    // (A)

    int result = 0;

    var resultTask = Task.Run(() => { result = source.Wait(); });

    // (B)

    resultTask.Wait();

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

This code tries to wait on a background thread. If we insert a call to `scheduler.Start()` at point (A), then `source.Wait()` will block forever.

This is because `Start()` will ONLY advance the internal clock of the `TestScheduler` until all currently scheduled events are executed. With a cold observable, events are scheduled relative to the virtual time of subscription. Since there are no subscribers at point (A), you will find that `TestScheduler.Now.Ticks` will report 0 even after the call to `Start()`.

Hmmm. Things get even worse if we move the call to `scheduler.Start()` to point B. Now we have a race condition! It's a race condition that will almost always result in the test hanging at the call to `resultTask.Wait()`. This is because the chances are that the `resultTask` will not have had time to execute it's action and subscribe to `source` before the `scheduler.Start()` call executes - and so time once again will not advance.

A deterministic execution is therefore very hard to achieve - there is no nice way to announce that the `Wait()` call has been issued before advancing time, since the Wait() call itself will block. Inserting a long enough delay before calling `Start()` will work, but kind of defeats the object of using the `TestScheduler`:

```
// (B)
Task.Delay(2000).Wait();        
scheduler.AdvanceBy(200);
```

What this question really demonstrates to me (IMHO) is that calling `Wait()` and blocking a thread is almost always a bad idea. Look for using methods like `LastAsync()` instead, and/or using continuations to get hold of results to asynchronous methods.

I can't recommend the approach due to the complexity, but here is a deterministic solution that makes use of an extension method to signal when a subscription has been made.

```
void Main()
{
    var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
    var source = scheduler.CreateColdObservable(
        new Recorded<Notification<int>>(100, Notification.CreateOnNext(1)),
        new Recorded<Notification<int>>(200, Notification.CreateOnCompleted<int>()));

    // (A)      
    var waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    int result = 0;                         
    var resultTask = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        result = source.AnnounceSubscription(waitHandle).Wait();
    });

    // (B)
    waitHandle.WaitOne();   
    scheduler.Start();

    resultTask.Wait();

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

public static class ObservableExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<T> AnnounceSubscription<T>(
        this IObservable<T> source, AutoResetEvent are)
    {
        return Observable.Create<T>(o =>
        {
            var sub = source.Subscribe(o);
            are.Set();
            return sub;
        });
    }
}
```

#### Recommended approach for testing Rx

A more idiomatic use of the `TestScheduler` is to create an observer to collect results, and then assert they meet expectations. Something like:

```
void Main()
{
    var scheduler = new TestScheduler();
    var source = scheduler.CreateColdObservable(
        new Recorded<Notification<int>>(100, Notification.CreateOnNext(1)),
        new Recorded<Notification<int>>(200, Notification.CreateOnCompleted<int>()));

    var results = scheduler.CreateObserver<int>();

    // here you would append to source the Rx calls that do something interesting
    source.Subscribe(results);

    scheduler.Start();

    results.Messages.AssertEqual(
        new Recorded<Notification<int>>(100, Notification.CreateOnNext(1)),
        new Recorded<Notification<int>>(200, Notification.CreateOnCompleted<int>()));   
}
```

Finally, if you derive a unit test class from `ReactiveTest` you can take advantage of `OnNext`, `OnCompleted` and `OnError` helper methods to create `Recorded<Notification<T>>` instances in a more readable fashion.

Comment: + for explaining where the OnNext, OnCompleted, OnError methods originate from.